# is it possible to disable comments to posts or hide comments made by friends from other friends?

Tags: facebook, comments

is there any way to disable comments so that friends cannot comment my posts?
if not is there any way to hide from a friend or a group of friends (by default) comments made to my posts by other friends?

Answer (score -1):

No. The only way is to share via group

Comment: Sources? Any explanation of how to set up the group sharing?

Comment: Facebook allow you only restrict visibility of posts but not allow you restrict comments, likes etc... If somebody can see posts he can comment... Than you post something there is an icon with man... This feature'll let you share only via friends for instance